# how to set path for this created file in an argument

Tags: java, file

How do I set path for this created file? The user should specify the path in his arguments. Currently this code is able to create a file. The user needs to store this file wherever he wants. I am doing this in Netbeans.

```
File file = new File("Export.xml");
System.out.println(file.getName());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter
(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

Comment: Where did you have trouble extending this small snippet of code to accept an argument?

Comment: i don't know how to do it. am newer to java.

Comment: *"the user should specify the path in his arguments."* Offer the user a `JFileChooser`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply append your filename to the path.

```
public void export(String path) {
    File file = new File( path + File.separator + "Export.xml" );
    ... 
}

public void caller() {
    export("C:\\temp" ); 
}
```